# Is this odometry considered bad?

Tags: navigation, odometry, kobuki, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i am using kobuki base. I read the it comes with factory calibrated gyro, however, i am having hard time mapping out a 30m x 100m(roughly) library layout. The map is always off when i am driving it on the two column or onwards (kobuki thought that she is still moving on the column before).

I am unable to upload a photo yet, so i link it to google photos.

This is my first screenshot: [link text](http://www.flickr.com/photos/112691678@N08/11579575793/)

and this is a screenshot 4 mins after: [link text](http://www.flickr.com/photos/112691678@N08/11580151426/)

Should i try to calibrate its gyro as the tutorial for create base? Or anything i could do to get the map out?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/112941/is-this-odometry-considered-bad?/) by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-12-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-12-26**:
Your links appear to be password protected. I cannot see them.

**Comment by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on 2013-12-26**:
my apologies, i have posted them on flikr. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That doesn't look like terrible odometry as most of the lines seem straight. It looks like you ended up with an incorrect match at some point which pulled you out of alignment. If you had a ground truth it would be easier to compare. Typical odometry tests for odometry is to drive in a known patter and compare the output of a closed loop trajectory.

You may be able to tune the gmapping parameters better for your platform. I would also suggest doing a more incremental exploration and coming back to the area you started more often instead of making a large loop and trying to close it at once. Gmapping doesn't reoptimize the whole map only recent loop closures.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on 2013-12-27**:
is 'If you had a ground truth it would be easier to compare. Typical odometry tests for odometry is to drive in a known patter and compare the output of a closed loop trajectory' referring for the need to do a odometry calibration? as in compare how far it is off in a known path taken with the odom?